# The set of critic points for $f(x)=x^{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ if $x\neq0$ and $0$ if $x=0$, is not closed.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as: 
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> x^{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{if }x\neq0,\\
> 0 & \text{if }x=0.
> \end{cases}$$
>    Prove that the set of critic points of $f$ is not a closed set.

I tried to do the next. From the definiton of $f$, for each integer
$k\neq0$ we have that $f\left(\frac{1}{k\pi}\right)=0$ and $f(0)=0$
also. Then using Rolle's theorem we have that for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}-\{ 1\} $,
there exists $x_{k}\in\left(\frac{1}{k\pi},\frac{1}{\left(k-1\right)\pi}\right)$
such that $f'(x_{k})=0$. Also I have for the derivative
that:
$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{if }x\neq0,\\
0 & \text{if }x=0.
\end{cases}$$
 So I have that all these numbers $x_{k}$ and $0$ are critic points
of $f$. But if I consider the set of all these numbers, this set
is closed. I think that may be there are more critic points for $f$
that I've not found such a way that this set is not closed, but I
don't know how to find them.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If by "critical point" you mean a point $c$ such that $f'(c) = 0$, then I think I agree that the set of critical points is closed. Analysis shows that $f'(0) = 0$, and some algebra shows that when $x \neq 0$, $f'(x) = 0$ if and only if $\frac{1}{x} = 2\tan \frac{1}{x}$. Thus, the set of critical points of $f$ is $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \frac{1}{x} = 2\tan \frac{1}{x} \} \cup \{0\}$. This set is indeed closed.

Comment: The result would be true for $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ (with $f(0)=0$), provided you don't count the points where $f$ is not differentiable among the critical points.